# declare a variable to use in multiple files in javascript

Tags: javascript, var

I am editing a website. I have one main page and one secundary page. In the main page, I want to have two links, both linked to the same secundary page. In the secundary page, I have a form hidden, which appears when a button is click. The difference I want to achieve between both links is:
-when the user clicks on the first link, the secundary page appears normally, with the form hidden (this is already working, and when the button is clicked the form appears, using a slidetoggle function).
-when the user clicks on the second link, the secundary page appears showing the form.

I am trying to use javascript, although I have very very raw knowledge, and my idea was creating a variable in the index (main) page called initia = 0, and when the user clicks on the second link, initia changes to 1. And then reuse this variable in the secondary page file, and just check if initia is 1 or 0. But I think it is not working like this. How should I do it?

The code I have now, although not working, is:

```
    //in the main page
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var inici = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".x").click(function()
     {
            inici = 2;
        });});
    </script>

//in the secundary page
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $(".msg_body").hide(); 
            $(".msg_head").click(function()
            {
                $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle();
            });//until here normal behaviour
            if (inici > 1) { //to check if it should b already opened
                $(".msg_body").show();
                inici = 0;
            }});
        </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the link for the "form hidden" version be something like this:

```
page.html
```

and the one with the form showing be something like this:

```
page.html#form
```

(both use the same file; the second one just has some extra stuff at the end)

Then have your JavaScript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if(document.location.hash !== "#form") {
        $(".msg_body").hide(); 
        $(".msg_head").click(function()
        {
            $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle();
        });
    }
 });
```

this means that the form will only be hidden if the page is accessed without `#form` in the URL. No need to use any `inici` variable.

Comment: F* perfect, I would say. Thank you so much :) My question has been solved!!

Comment: How could I, automatically, when the form is shown (#form), scroll down the page a bit, in order to see the start of the form at the top, not in the middle of the screen. Something in html just uses #, I think?

Comment: Adding an `id="form"` attribute to the form should accomplish that. If it already has an ID, you can just use that ID in my example above instead of "form".

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using global variables. You should try using [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), which is linked to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work (to my understanding) because the Javascript from the main page stops running when the Javascript on the second page starts running. So, while inici does get changed when the linked is clicked, I believe the second page sees a new instance of inici which you initialize to 0.

I think a more effective way would be to simply POST some data to the second page when you transfer the user after clicking on the respective link. Then, the second page can read the POST data and decide if it should show the form or not.